# This String to JSON using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm writing a javascript animation script and I want people to be able to specify behaviour declaratively in the HTML.

This is what I want my HTML to look like:

```
<div data-animation="top: 600, left: 600, opacity: 1, start: 0.2, finish: 0.8"></div>
```

This obviously isn't valid JSON, but you can't write valid JSON in HTML. Is there a way to turn this into JSON?

I want to be able to get the attribute value and turn it straight into a javascript object that I can use without having to manually parse the string. I.e. I want this:

```
var example = {
    top: 600,
    left: 600,
    opacity: 1,
    start: 0.2,
    finish: 0.8
};
```

Comment: did you try  `data-animation="{top: 600, left: 600, opacity: 1, start: 0.2, finish: 0.8}" `

Comment: might help you http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/un0domue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more manual approch :

```
function getParametters(divId)
{
    var retObj = {}
    jQuery.each($("#" + divId).attr("data-animation").split(","),
    function(index, value){
        var spliced = value.split(":");
        retObj[spliced[0].trim()] = spliced[1].trim();
    });
    return retObj;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid manual parsing but having seen the alternatives I accept that this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can, using [`JSON.parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
$('div[data-animation]').each(function() {
    var json = JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-animation'));
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dufwbdr6/).

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer.  `JSON.parse()` provides the exact functionality the OP requested.

Comment: This doesn't fulfil the exact functionality because it requires the use to single quotes for the HTML and then valid JSON written into the attribute. This is different to the HTML posted in the original question, part of the problem being that it isn't in a format that JSON.parse will handle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `eval()`.

> The eval() method evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

See the following

```
var animationString = $('div').data('animation');
eval('({' + animationString + '})');
```

Run this in your console to see how it works:

```
eval('({top: 600, left: 600, opacity: 1, start: 0.2, finish: 0.8})');
```

The above code returns the following Object:

```
Object {top: 600, left: 600, opacity: 1, start: 0.2, finish: 0.8}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Nicely done. Do you mind explaining why you gotta put parentheses inside the string?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil . Code injection should not be a problem in your case and the performance hit you might take should be very minimal and hardly noticeable, but ultimately its up to you whether you use it or not.

Comment: Agreed, your link makes some good arguments. However, this code might be used by other developers and I don't want to give the impression that eval is generally okay to use.

Comment: No worries, would have chosen the other solution myself. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
   var a = $("div").data("animation");
   var b = JSON.stringify(a);
   var obj = JSON.parse(b);

   console.log(obj);
});
```

Comment: your answer is too close.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class or id to the div and access the attribute value and store in to a object like below.

```
var animation=$('.classname').attr('data-animation');
```